# Creating a Dynamic InnerBlock that updates depending on state

Tags: block-editor

I am creating a block that will use Innerblocks to Dynamically add additional tabs depending on the number selected by the user. This  number shall be passed through a Range Control.

Currently I have

```
 class Test extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super()
            this.state = {
                count: attributes.tabNumber
            }
            this.addTab = this.addTab.bind(this)
            this.removeTab = this.removeTab.bind(this)
        }

        addTab() {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                const updatedCount = prevState.count + 1
                setAttributes({tabNumber: updatedCount})
                return {
                    count: updatedCount
                }
            })
        }

        removeTab() {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                const updatedCount = prevState.count - 1
                setAttributes({ tabNumber: updatedCount })
                return {
                    count: updatedCount
                }
            })
        }

        render() {
            let getTabbedContent = count => {
                let templates = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    templates.push([
                        'cs/tab'
                    ]);
                }
                return templates;
            }

            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
                    <h2>{attributes.tabNumber}</h2>
                    <button onClick={this.addTab}>Add Tab</button>
                    <button onClick={this.removeTab}>Remove Tab</button>
                    <InnerBlocks
                        allowedBlocks={ALLOWED}
                        template={getTabbedContent(attributes.tabNumber)}
                        templateLock={true}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

The desired effect shall be when the Range Control (Or in this current case the buttons) are pressed an Inner block of cs/tab is added or removed.

Not the worlds neatest of code but currently working on creating it before shrinking it. This has also been my first full dive into the Class system of React.

addTab() and removeTab() were added for testing purposes.

Comment: You have not explained your problem.  What is working?  What isn't working?

Comment: Apologies. I made a quick amendment.
When you click add or remove button this should rerender the InnerBlock as per the renger() method for react but I am unable to make it do so

Comment: Take a look at how the core [columns block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src/columns) work, it might give you some help.